# How can I ensure if there is no crypto currency mining script running on my ubuntu?

Tags: security, bitcoin

I feel that my newly (5 months old) bought Lenovo laptop is running very slow and hangs sometimes from last few days. The only applications running on my laptop are chrome & firefox browsers, sublime and draw.io. All are light weighted. I have run the top command which shows me that `Xorg` and `compiz` are taking maximum of CPU.

Being a bit skeptic, I heard a news where some sites may run crypto currency mining scripts even when you close the browser. I would like to know is there any way I can know when such scripts make your machine dirty. Or if I can run some tool manually to know about such scripts and can remove them.

Comment: Cryptomining scripts are just another form of malware. Is there a particular reason you want to ignore those other forms of malware?

Comment: I'm not ignoring any type of malware. I would like to scan and remove all type of malware. The reason to ask about specific one can be said as "news effect" :). However I feel that my laptop becomes slow specially when I use draw.io

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question: "Xorg and compiz are taking maximum of CPU". Both of those are essential elements of your GUI; neither is malware.

Comment: Hmm probably. I have 4gb Graphics card. Do I need to enable something to use of GPU for GUI processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had cryptomining script running you should see them when you use `top` command as chromium/firefox/(or else) process. If no browser process are running, the issue is certainly somewhere else.

For your performance, maybe try to disable all desktop effect and see if there is differences and check if your hardware is well supported (graphic driver, etc.).

And about cryptomining script, I advise you to use an Web Extension in your browser, such as uBlock or even uMatrix if you want to block absolutly all by default.
Also the NoCoin extension is made specially to avoid cryptomining scripts running in your browser.

Comment: Thanks. I have ensured using top command that no browser process is running.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the only answer but thanks for tricky check.